# C++: setting time using suffixes

Tags: c++, c++11, time, c++14, user-defined-literals

Tell me, Can the following exist in C ++ 11/14/17:

1) set time using time suffixes

```
double time1 = 1s; // time1 = 1.0
double time2 = 2m; // time2 = 120.0
double time3 = 7ms; // time3 = 0.007
```

2) get the string value of the time with the suffix as set

```
std::cout << getTime(time1); // cout 1s
std::cout << getTime(time2); // cout 2s
std::cout << getTime(time3); // cout 7ms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, as of C++14, you can use the user-defined literals [described here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) to create durations:

   ```
   #include <chrono>
   using namespace std::literals;
   auto time1 = 1s; // std::chrono::seconds{1}
   auto time2 = 2min; // std::chrono::minutes{2}
   auto time3 = 7ms; // std::chrono::milliseconds{7}
   ```

   These create type-safe objects that store an integral value. You can use `double` internally fairly easily, but those specializations don't come with a pretty type alias out of the box:

   ```
   namespace chr = std::chrono;
   using dbl_seconds = chr::duration<double, chr::seconds::period>;
   // Likewise for other units
   dbl_seconds time1 = 1s;
   ```

   If you absolutely need the internal value (usually a bad idea), you can access it with `.count()`.
2. This is planned to come in C++20:

   ```
   std::cout << time1; // 1s, or 1.000000s if using double
   ```

   Until then, the best you can do with standard C++ is to suck it up and use `count()`:

   ```
   std::cout << time1.count() << 's'; // 1s
   ```

For a good look into the library, watch [Howard's CppCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M). His other talks cover the planned C++20 additions.

Answer (score 5):

1. **Yes**, via [std::chrono_literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono#Literals).
2. **Not directly**, but you can print the `typeid` (usable for debugging) or provide overloads for streaming durations yourself.

I have included explicit overloads of `operator<<` here, but as *[@JeJo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9609840/jejo?tab=profile)*, it can also be done with templates: https://wandbox.org/permlink/o495eXlv4rQ3z6yP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

// example overloads for streaming out durations
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::nanoseconds& v) {
    return os << v.count() << "ns";
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::microseconds& v) {
    return os << v.count() << "us";
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::milliseconds& v) {
    return os << v.count() << "ms";
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::seconds& v) {
    return os << v.count() << "s";
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::minutes& v) {
    return os << v.count() << "min";
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::hours& v) {
    return os << v.count() << "h";
}

int main() {
    auto time1 = 1s;
    auto time2 = 2min;
    auto time3 = 7ms;
    std::cout << time1.count() << " " << typeid(time1).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << time2.count() << " " << typeid(time2).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << time3.count() << " " << typeid(time3).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << time1 << "\n";
    std::cout << time2 << "\n";
    std::cout << time3 << "\n";
}
```

Possible output:

```
1 NSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1EEEE
2 NSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl60ELl1EEEE
7 NSt6chrono8durationIlSt5ratioILl1ELl1000EEEE
1s
2min
7ms
```

Answer (score 4):

**All of the modern C++ time utilities are described in [the reference for `<chrono>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)**

1. **Yes**, starting from [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) we have `std::literals::chrono_literals`,
   allowing us to use following literals:

   ```
   operator""h
   operator""min
   operator""s
   operator""ms
   operator""us
   operator""ns
   ```

   For example (from
   [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22h)):

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <chrono>

   int main()
   {
       using namespace std::chrono_literals;
       auto day = 24h;
       auto halfhour = 0.5h;
       std::cout << "one day is " << day.count() << " hours\n"
                 << "half an hour is " << halfhour.count() << " hours\n";
   }
   ```

---

2. **Not directly**, but starting from [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) there exists
   [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration),
   with several convenient helper types to help describe time correctly
   (e.g. `std::chrono::millisceonds`, `std::chrono::hours` etc.). Using
   those, you can easily do what is needed.

   Shortened example from
   [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).
   As you can see, unit has to be printed separately, but choosing the
   right unit to print would be easy enough with some template magic.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <chrono>

   int main()
   {     
       std::chrono::seconds sec(1);

       std::cout << sec.count() <<" second is equal to:\n";

       // integer scale conversion with no precision loss: no cast
       std::cout << std::chrono::microseconds(sec).count() << " microseconds\n";

       // integer scale conversion with precision loss: requires a cast
       std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(sec).count()
                 << " minutes\n";
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

1) No

2) No, not directly. There exist the operators to convert to the chrono types (though that is on integers and not on doubles) but they don't have `operator<<` overloads. `boost::chrono` has pretty printers (they are deprecated though). However, they are fully written out and not just the short form.

See:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration
- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/chrono.html

Comment: Umm, clearly the answer to the first question is "yes". I suggest you delete this answer or you will get downvoted pretty quick.

Comment: No, the literals create the chrono types (as mentioned under 2). The OP example creates doubles.

Comment: ... then rewrite your one-word answer to explain this is what you mean.